# Property of a node not being displayed

Tags: neo4j

I created 2 nodes:

```
create
  (g:gomma:composizione_chimica{tipo:'gomma'}),
  (c:composizione_chimica{name:'composizione chimica'})
```

When I try to visualize in the graph frame the properties instead of ID by clicking the `:composizione_chimica` label, on the frame bottom there's only the `{tipo}`property available. So node g hate property "gomma" displayed, node c nothing. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the web UI doesn't handle multiple labels ideally in situations like this.

If you just do a query for that one node like:

```
MATCH (c:composizione_chimica) WHERE c.name = 'composizione chimica' RETURN c
```

Then you should be able to choose the name.

Alternatively if you enter `:style` in the bar it will bring up a model where you can download a `.grass` file (a format made for Neo4j), edit it with your change locally, and then upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you plz explain what is your exact problem? As per I understand you have given same label `:composizione_chimica` to both node. So the node c which have label `:composizione_chimica` will only show you property `{name:'composizione chimica'}`  and node g which have both label `:gomma` and `:composizione_chimica` will show you property `{tipo:'gomma'}`

Comment: the problem is that when clicking the node `(c)` in the bottom bar (where there are all nodes parameters) it only shows the property `{tipo}`which, in this node is not present. So the displayed node results empty.